Are Pseudonymized Facebook Identifiers (PFBIDs) permalinks?
Are Pseudonymized Facebook Identifiers (PFBIDs)-containing URLs "permalinks", or will they
blow up in my face after a few months? E.g.,

Ralph, that link you gave me to that Facebook article no longer works.
Thanks a lot. I thought you said you were an IT professional.

